# RSpec Issue with have_css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec

I'm using Rails 5.1.1, RSpec 3.5.0 & Capybara 2.7.1.

I want to have a test that checks for a navbar on the home page, according to some documents that I've found I should be using `have_css` for this. The example given is:
`have_css("input#movie_title")`

My understanding is that this would look for an `input` tag with an id of *movie_title*. Is that correct?

I'm trying this in my code:
`have_css("div.navbar-default")`

I get this error, however:
`Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css("div.navbar-default") expected to find css "div.navbar-default" but there were no matches`

Why is this not working? I have a div with the class 'navbar-default', so this should work as far as I can work out.

**Edit / Solved:**
I realised my mistake. I have to expect statements, the `navbar-default` class is in a nav tag, *not* a div tag. The 2nd statement is in a div tag but wasn't running due to the error on the first one.

I've fixed it now, all working

Comment: Can you post that related div code?

Comment: @Pavan realised my mistake. navbar-default was in a nav tag, not a div tag. I have another have_css below it that _was_ in a div, but it wasn't getting to the because of the 1st error. Fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

The `have_css` matcher is applied to the parent container instead of the actual element. Is there a parent container?

Try something like this:

```
# Find the parent
parent = page.find('div#nav')
# Check for the nested div 
expect(parent).to have_css(".navbar-default")
```